# Javascript/HTML mobile browser emulator

Tags: javascript, web, emulation, mobile-browser

Looking for an html/js solution/package to display a website preview on my site, where the previewed site is rendered as if it was viewed by a mobile browser.

Currently I am using a solution based on an iFrame, however this does not allow me to set the user agent to a mobile one, so it is not an optimal solution.

Suggestions appreciated.

EDIT: 
I don't think I made myself clear enough, I want to embed such an emulator on my webpage, I am not looking for a browser extension or for a desktop software solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
Just to update and specify what I eventually did:

What I needed to do is embed some kind of iframe which emulates webpages as if they were viewed from a mobile device. The biggest problem was to set the user agent to be a mobile one (which you cannot do with an iframe).
What I ended up doing is set up another php-based server running a glype proxy.
The Glype proxy allows to emulate different user agents, I hard coded it to be an android browser user agent.

I then inserted an iframe pointing to my other proxy server, and it works nice.

I still had a problem with some websites which implement and iframebuster script, and I had to manage that.

Ilan

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Ripple Emulator** it emulates many devices and many platforms.

first open chrome(chrome adds on) ,open this [URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) on chrome :

add it on chrome ,
you can then enable it on disable it as you need,
(write click enable/disable)

see how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of emulators available for mobile devices. Some prominent ones are:

- [Ripple Emulator for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en)
- [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/)
- Also checkout, [this page](http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators) on MobileX for a complete catalog.